# Save pfx certificate to file with java code (ejbca)

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, pkcs#12, ejbca

i use EJBCA to generate a certificate from a CommonName. In java code i have generated private key and public key and then the csr for generate the certificate. 
Now i save the certificate in PEM format (.cer), but i need also private key so i want save with .pfx or p12 extension. How can i do?
This is my actual code for generate certificate:

```
KeyPair keys;
    try {
        keys = KeyTools.genKeys("1024", AlgorithmConstants.KEYALGORITHM_RSA);   

        //SAVE PRIVKEY
        //PrivateKey privKey = keys.getPrivate();
        //byte[] privateKeyBytes = privKey.getEncoded();
        PKCS10CertificationRequest  pkcs10 = new PKCS10CertificationRequest("SHA256WithRSA",
                CertTools.stringToBcX509Name("CN=NOUSED"), keys.getPublic(), null, keys.getPrivate());
        //Print Privatekey
        //System.out.println(keys.getPrivate().toString());
        CertificateResponse certenv =  ws.certificateRequest(user1,
                                                               new String(Base64.encode(pkcs10.getEncoded())),
                                                                CertificateHelper.CERT_REQ_TYPE_PKCS10,
                                                                null,
                                                                CertificateHelper.RESPONSETYPE_CERTIFICATE);

        //Certificate certenv =  ejbcaraws.pkcs10Req("WSTESTUSER1","foo123",new 
        //String(Base64.encode(pkcs10.getEncoded())),null);

        return certenv.getCertificate (); 
    }catch (Exception e) {}
```

and with this i save the certificate:

```
File file = new File(path+"/"+ x509Cert.getSubjectDN().toString().replace("CN=", "") +".cer");

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);  
        //os.write("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n".getBytes("US-ASCII"));  
        //os.write(Base64.encode(x509Cert.getEncoded(), true));  
        //os.write("-----END CERTIFICATE-----".getBytes("US-ASCII"));  
        //os.close(); 

        PEMWriter pemWriter = new PEMWriter(new PrintWriter(os));
        pemWriter.writeObject(x509Cert);
        pemWriter.flush();
        pemWriter.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

I never use `EJBCA`, however if you have the certificate and the private key and you want to create a `PKCS12` you can use `setKeyEntry(String alias,byte[] key,Certificate[] chain)` method from `java.security.KeyStore` to add the entry, and then `store(OutputStream stream, char[] password)` method to save the `PKCS12` on a file (look at [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) for more details). Your code could be something like:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

public class SamplePKCS12 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String alias = // the alias for your key...
        PrivateKey key = // your private key
        Certificate[] chain = // an array with your EE certificate to your CA issuer
        // create keystore      
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        // add your key and cert        
        keystore.setKeyEntry(alias, key.getEncoded(), chain);
        // save the keystore to file
        keystore.store(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/keystore.p12"), "yourPin".toCharArray());
    }
}
```

Note I suppose that you have your certificate and your private key as you said in your question. To work with `PKCS12` you need `SunJSSE` provider (which is normally loaded by default), or alternatively you can use `BouncyCastle` provider.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I use a the KeyPair to generate a public/private keypair in the code, and created the certificate. Now, later on in a different request I wish to retrieve the p12 which was generated in a different request. In this situation how do I generate the p12 ?

Comment: @sbose This is a different question... if I understand well you want to load a PKCS12 from a previous created file isn't it? then you only have to use `keystore.load` method to load the file (using for example a `fileInputStream`). Basically something like: `KeyStore kstore= KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
kstore.load(new FileInputStream("/somePath/yourP12File.p12"), "yourPassword".toCharArray()); ...`

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, create a pkcs12 from a previously generated certificate. The Certificate is present in the database in the CertificateData table.

Comment: @sbose If in your database you only store the certificate (not the `PKCS12`) then you can instantiate it using  `CertificateFactory` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html) passing the byte you get from the database... If you need a more detailed response I think that it's better that you ask a new question providing all the details `:)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223358/fetch-pre-generated-p12-certificate-from-ejbca

Thanks a lot. I've tested out using CertificateFactory , but I used the private key from the KeyPair used to generated the certificate. However in this case, all I have is the Certificate object from the getCertificate call.