# Fetch pre-generated p12 certificate from EJBCA

Tags: security, certificate, pki, pkcs#12, ejbca

I am using the following API to fetch a certificate previously generated in EJBCA:

https://www.ejbca.org/older_releases/ejbca_4_0/htdocs/ws/org/ejbca/core/protocol/ws/client/gen/EjbcaWS.html#getCertificate(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

The Private+public key was generated in the code, and hence I haven't persisted it anywhere.

While setting the user status ( "editUser" ) I've used 
https://www.ejbca.org/older_releases/ejbca_4_0/htdocs/ws/org/ejbca/core/protocol/ws/client/gen/UserDataVOWS.html#TOKEN_TYPE_P12

- How do I get the p12 certificate now? I'm getting the .crt file ( which has only the public key ).
- Does EJBCA persist the Private keys somewhere?
- Would the EJBCA Keystore be of help?

Comment: what do you exactly want? do you want to getconnection to ejbca web service or want to issue a new certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the pkcs12Req WS method to generate a server generated p12 file.